# How is concurrency managed in volumes when they are shared by multiple containers?

Tags: docker, kubernetes

How is concurrency managed in volumes when the volumes are shared by multiple containers?

Answer (score 1):

It is the same way how a shared path / directory / file is managed by multiple processes / applications without containers.

1. Avoid parallel / simultaneous writes using locks, semaphores, mutexes and mutual exclusion.
2. Be careful about stale / old data when reading from shared volume.
3. Keep in mind things like eventual consistency, volume backups and data migration since the volume is shared by multiple containers.
4. Make sure that the shared volume is not corrupted. If corrupted, have a recovery plan.
5. Use dedicated storage servers so that containers can move in the cluster (**`hostPath`** and **`emptyDir`** in kubernetes do not move with pods).
6. The underlying OS, disk, storage software / driver, LVM, filesystem will also handle IO concurrency.

Comment: Well...and Which are those mutex? Because anybody can wrote something "you need a quantum computer." As say Linus Torvals "show me the code".

Comment: @tres.14159 Info about mutexes in Python, Golang and C++ are in https://docs.python.org/2/library/mutex.html, https://gobyexample.com/mutexes, http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/mutex/mutex/ respectively. Usage of mutexes in other programming languages can be found online too. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

As it would be on a single host with multiple processes, cause that's what it effectively is.